# sort Javascript object by value, returns wrong result

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I create the publicPostContent array with a Promise. Once that is finished creating. I see I have an array of 3 Javascript objects which I am trying to sort on the value of Grade which is for instance:
17.23949/ 25.50033/ 40.23245

I use the compare function as below, however this doesn't seem to work at all, I used different compare functions. But to no result.
I am starting to think my javascript Object is in the incorrect format?
I get no errors, but the sorting seems to give a different result each time I refresh.

the console.log(a) returns nothing.

```
this.publicPostContent[i] = {"_id": key._id,"timePast" : 
this.timePastPublic, "grade": this.publicPostGrade[i]}
this.publicPostContent.sort(this.compareValues('grade'));
```

---

```
compareValues(key, order = 'asc') {
    return function(a, b) {
        if (!a.hasOwnProperty(key) || !b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // property doesn't exist on either object
            return 0;
        }
        console.log(a)
        const varA = (typeof a[key] === 'string') ?
            a[key].toUpperCase() : a[key];
        const varB = (typeof b[key] === 'string') ?
            b[key].toUpperCase() : b[key];
        console.log(varA)
        let comparison = 0;
        if (varA > varB) {
            comparison = 1;
        } else if (varA < varB) {
            comparison = -1;
        }
        return (
            (order == 'desc') ? (comparison * -1) : comparison
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: Your function works. Just check if it's invoked properly

Comment: Is *this* referenced correctly? Is the function declared correctly? (I guess this is just the effect of a bad copy/paste, but that format works only on typescript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to sort by key

```js
var array =[{"grade":50.23949},{"grade":17.23949} ,{"grade":25.50033},{"grade":40.23245}];

function sortByKey(unSortArray,key)
{
  return unSortArray.sort(function(first, second)  
  {  
      if(!first.hasOwnProperty(key) || !first.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // property doesn't exist on either object
          return 0; 
      }
      if (first[key] == second[key])  
          return 0;  
      if (first[key] <  second[key])  
          return -1;  
      else  
          return 1;   
  });
}


var sortArray = sortByKey(array,"grade");
console.log(sortArray);
```

Comment: @oudekaas  is it working? If any problem please lets me know.Can you please mark this answer correct if answered is useful.